Как отправить приветственное сообщение только после одобрения заявки на вступление в чат?
@welcome.chat_join_request()
async def approve_user(update: ChatJoinRequest):
    # await update.approve()
    user_id = update.from_user.id
    username = update.from_user.username
    name = update.from_user.full_name
    if ChatMemberMember:
        if username:
            welcome_message = f"""<b>Приветсвую, <a href = 'https://t.me/{username}'>{name}</a>!</b>"""
        else:
            welcome_message = f"""<b>Приветсвую, <a href = 'tg://openmessage?user_id={user_id}'>{name}</a>!</b>"""
        
        await bot.send_message(chat_id=CHAT_ID, text=welcome_message, parse_mode='HTML')
    else:
        return    


Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.
